# Does update statement with PDO prepare return Data depending on setFetchMode?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Problem:

- First: update data by using update statement + PDO prepare
- Second: after updating data, push it to return data without using select statement

Note: if I use select sql statement after update execute, I can get the result but I want to use only update statement as what I have in code bellow:

```
.....
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'user', 'pwd');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($e->getMessage()); echo "</pre>";
}

$delete = $db->prepare("update membership set active = 0 where ID = :user_id");
$delete->execute([
        'user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']
]);

//Update cannot return result
$delete->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($delete->fetch()); echo "</pre>";
....
```

Comment: Then SELECT the record with the user_id ? (SELECT * FROM membership WHERE ID=:user-id)

Comment: @bub, thanks. I want to use only update statement after that I want to get data after updating without using select statement.

Comment: So you want to select data without a select statement? That's not going to work...

Comment: @jeroen, you are right. That why I raise the issue here. I can solve it if I use one more select sql statement as I wrote.

Comment: You cant get any data without using SELECT

Comment: you should look into using method chaining to return a result. This would allow you to fetch data after update has been complete. eg. $data->update()->getData() and set the return value of getData() to return your data. Tutorial on method chaining can be seen here.
http://www.techflirt.com/tutorials/oop-in-php/php-method-chaining.html

Comment: @Juakali92, thanks. I will try as you said. But I still use one more select statement. OK, I must use it.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. Database returns only number of affected records for `update` queries: [e.g. MySQL update docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).